# Summernote tool bar, remove scroll and show drop down

Tags: jquery, css, summernote

I'm using summernote-lite.min.js but having an issue that it's toll bar has scroll in it, due to which all drop down buttons appear inside that area and user has to scroll the toll bar to see the options. Attaching the screenshots of issue to clearly understand.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should first set `overflow: hidden` for parent and then in drop down list `z-index: 1000` 
this solution probably works...

Comment: where to add this css? Does it has to be added on initialization of summernote?

Comment: I don't have your code to tell you exactly where to put it...but search to find css code for parent that scrolled and put inside it